# Trying to get property of non-object.. I'm lost

Tags: php

```
<?php if($user->premium): ?>
        <p>You are premium!</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>You are not premium. <a href="premium.php">Go premium</a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm trying to create a premium method for my site I'm working on,but the code on the top dosnt work.

Comment: Where do you define `$user`?

Comment: in my init.php file which is required at the top of the page

Comment: And it is an object? `if (!is_object($user)) { echo ':( It is not an object'; }`

Comment: Actually once you mentioned where I defined it, I started thinking and running through my files, I actually made a test page that's alike and I required that one. I feel dumb, thanks a lot, Chris85!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `required` the wrong file in my project! :/
I was also missing `$user = new user();`, so the `$user` wasn't defined.

*@chris85 helped me solve my problem.  For some reason, I can't mark his comment as the answer.*